# AS3 : RegExp exec method in loop problem

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, loops

I need some help about RegExp in AS3.

I have a simple pattern :

```
patternYouTube = new RegExp ( "v(?:\/|=)([A-Z0-9_-]+)", "gi" );
```

This pattern is looking for the youTube id video.

For example :

```
var tmpUrl : String;    
var result : Object;
var toto : Array = new Array();
toto = ["http://www.youtube.com/v/J-vCxmjCm-8&autoplay=1", "http://www.youtube.com/v/xFTRnE1WBmU&autoplay=1"];
var i : uint;

for ( i = 0 ; i < toto.length ; i++)
{
     tmpUrl = toto[i];
     result = patternYouTube.exec ( tmpUrl );
     if ( result.length != 0 && result != null )
     {
         trace(result);
     }
}
```

When i == 0, it works perfectly.
Flash returns me : `v/J-vCxmjCm-8,J-vCxmjCm-8`

When i == 1, it fails.
Flash returns me : `null`

When I revert the two strings in my array such as :

```
toto = [ http://www.youtube.com/v/xFTRnE1WBmU&autoplay=1, http://www.youtube.com/v/J-vCxmjCm-8&autoplay=1 ];
```

When i == 0, it works perfectly :
Flash returns me : `xFTRnE1WBmU`

When i == 1, it fails :
Flash returns me : `null`

Do you have any idea about the problem in the loop ?

Comment: I am not so sure, but aren't the " missing on the array declarations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what `g`​lobal RegExps do in JavaScript/ActionScript. You `exec` them once, you get the first match, `exec` them again and get the second match. With a `g` RegExp you have to keep calling it again until you've got through all the matches. Then you'll get `null` and the search will reset to the start of the string.

It's a weird interface, but that's what we're stuck with. If you don't want this behaviour, omit the `'g'` flag from the `new RegExp` constructor. Then you'll get only the first match, every time.

Comment: You're totally right ! Thank you for helping me. Now I started to understand 'g' flag thanks to you.

Answer (score 3):

bobince is completely right but you can also set the lastIndex property to 0 before calling exec().

```
patternYouTube.lastIndex = 0;
```

Now you can have your g flag cake and eat it too... or er, um something like that...